# how to run a shell script at the first start of a linux vm

Tags: linux, debian

I want to know how I can run a shell script at the first start of my Linux VM.
The shell script must be run only once.

I'm on Debian 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a flag file (`/root/.firstrun` in my example below) to check whether the script has already been executed or not.

Add this to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
if [ ! -e /root/.firstrun ]
then
        /path/to/your_script.sh
        touch /root/.firstrun
fi
```

Or, if you don't need the script after the execution, you can use the script itself as the flag:

```
myscript="/path/to/your_script.sh"
if [ -x "$myscript" ]
then
        $myscript && rm -f "$myscript"
fi
```

Comment: You could use the script file itself as the the flag - `if test -x $script; then $script; rm $script; fi`.

Comment: I've thought about it but perhaps the OP wants to leave the script on the machine, for later checks. I've added your suggestion to the answer.

Comment: This doesn't work. In fact i didnt have rc.local file so i created them, but I have the impression that he does not run the rc.local file :/

Comment: Yes; when I've done this, I've replaced the `rm` with something more like `mv $script $script.done`.  N.B. you probably didn't want `&&` - but that depends a lot on the system requirements.

Comment: No, this is the first part that does not work. 
I do not need the second so I did not integrate it

Comment: `rc.local` must be executable. Have you checked if this is the case?